# How do I request a new refresh token when the last one expired?

Tags: oauth, docusignapi

I have two accounts for docusign, live and demo. The demo one hasn't been used in a while, in fact the last time a refresh token was created was the 14th November. I'm therefore assuming it has expired and is potentially stopping me from getting a new one.

When I make a request I get the invalid_grant error. The same code (with testing credentials) works fine with my live account which requests a live token every couple of days or so. It also did work fine on with the testing credentials until it wasn't used for a prolonged period.

I assumed I need to get hold of a new refresh token but without a valid previous token I'm not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot refresh a Refresh Token if the Refresh Token has expired or otherwise been revoked. You must repeat the authentication flow to obtain a new Refresh Token.

Comment: Mostly true, but...with DocuSign's implementation, you can refresh the refresh token if it hasn't yet expired and you have the `extended` scope.

Comment: Is there no way to programatically get a new refresh token? I don't see why the admin needs to manually go through the authorization grant protocol every time.

Comment: No, you cannot programmatically get a new Refresh Token for an expired or revoked Refresh Token. You must go thru the authorization flow again.

Comment: Does this mean that typical apps like instragram, snapchat, etc. have an infinite expiry date for their refresh token?
Because I have never needed to log in again since the first time I logged into these apps about 8 years ago.

Comment: @FireFuro99 - Post a new question. Include details such as the type of device. Some vendors treat iPhones differently than desktops.

Answer (score 5):

The following applies to DocuSign's OAuth2 authentication service:

When you use the refresh token to get a new access token, you also get a new refresh token. But see the following:

If your original OAuth request only included the `signature` scope then the expiration date of the new refresh token will be the same as the original refresh token (30 days).

However, if you request both the `signature` and `extended` scopes, then your new refresh token will expire 30 days from the time that you refreshed it.

So the way you can continue to get a new access token without requiring the user to authenticate again is:

1. User authenticates with the `signature` and `extended` scopes. Your app exchanges the auth code for an access token (good for 8 hours) and a refresh token (good for 30 days).
2. Within the 30 day period, refresh the access token. This also gives you a new refresh token, good for a new 30 day period.
3. Rinse and repeat. As long as you get a new refresh token at least every 30 days, you can keep going forever.

Caveat: For InfoSec reasons, the end user, their admin, and/or DocuSign might invalidate all existing refresh tokens. This is an unusual corner case but can happen. Easiest way to test the corner case: remove the user's consent for the app.